# PCA: How to get the vector that points to the origin of the new coordinate system?

Tags: r, pca

The PCA projects the original data points into a new coordinate system and I would like to determine the vector that connects the origin of the old coordinate system with the origin of the new coordinate system in R.

This is what I have coded so far:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(c(5,15,21,29,31,43,49,51,61,65),
c(33,35,24,21,27,16,18,10,4,12)))


# Subtract columns by their mean and 
# divide with their standard deviation
scaled_data <- scale(data, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
scaled_data
plot(scaled_data)

# Correlation Matrix
corrmat <- cor(scaled_data)
corrmat

# Compute Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors
eigen <- eigen(corrmat)

eigenvectors <- eigen$vectors
eigenvectors

eigenvalues <- eigen$values
eigenvalues

# Transform data
transformed_data <- (data.matrix(scaled_data) %*% eigenvectors)*sqrt(2)
transformed_data

plot(transformed_data)
```

Comment: Possibly stupid question (mine, not yours): why would the origins not be identical? What does it buy you to include a translation of the origin as part of the transformation?

Comment: What's the origin of the `sqrt(2)` term when computing the scores?  Thx.

Comment: I took this value from a book to obtain simple numbers for the transformed data. Must have forgotten to delete it. Just forget about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of the new coordinate system is the barycenter (a.k.a. center of mass) of your data set:

```
colMeans(data)
# X1 X2 
# 37 20
```